# Fractional cascading vs merge

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, binary-search

Fractional cascading allows me to search in k ordered lists. It requires every list to have same ordering (how would I otherwise insert elements from the cascade below, preserving order?). But why is this better than merging those k lists and doing binary search on it?

Comment: [Fractional cascading (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_cascading#Example) has the answer to your question: roughly speaking, fractional cascading acheives better space and/or time complexities than merge&binary search.